# Create a pivot table in pandas while adding up the number of occurrences in a column

Tags: pandas

#### Setup

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
    fruit   color   region   subregion
0   banana  yellow  CANADA   TORONTO
1   pear    red     CANADA   MONTREAL
2   banana  red     CANADA   TORONTO
3   banana  yellow  CANADA   TORONTO
4   banana  yellow  CANADA   MONTREAL
5   apple   red     US       GEORGIA
6   banana  red     US       IOWA
7   banana  yellow  CANADA   MONTREAL
8   apple   red     CANADA   MONTREAL
9   banana  yellow  CANADA   MONTREAL
```

I want to pivot the dataframe to count the number of times each row pair `(fruit, color)` appears in each region and subregion.

```
fruit   color   US   CANADA   TORONTO   MONTREAL   GEORGIA   IOWA
apple   red     1    1        0          0         1         0
apple   yellow  0    0        0          0         0         0
pear    red     0    1        0          1         0         0
banana  yellow  0    5        2          3         0         0
banana  red     1    1        2          0         0         1
```

#### Attempts

If we ignore the `subregion` by dropping the column entirely, we can get pretty close by doing:

```
df.groupby(['fruit', 'color', 'region']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

which gets us:

```
region  fruit   color   US   CANADA   
0       apple   red     1    1        
1       apple   yellow  0    0        
2       pear    red     0    1        
3       banana  yellow  0    5        
4       banana  red     1    1
```

It may not be the most elegant solution (and there is something going in with the indexing here that I don't quite understand) but then you could repeat this process and then join the two tables.

My question is: is there a more elegant, pandas-native way of doing the operation I'm describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `melt` and `pivot_table` is an option:

```py
cols = ['fruit', 'color']
(df.melt(id_vars=cols)
   .pivot_table(index=cols,
                columns='value', 
                aggfunc='size', 
                fill_value=0)
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)

    fruit   color  CANADA  GEORGIA  IOWA  MONTREAL  TORONTO  US
0   apple     red       1        1     0         1        0   1
1  banana     red       1        0     1         0        1   1
2  banana  yellow       5        0     0         3        2   0
3    pear     red       1        0     0         1        0   0
```

Comment: `melt` followed by `pivot_table` is a really clever pattern -- I just used it in a different context to solve a slightly different problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) for this.

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['fruit', 'color']), prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    fruit   color  CANADA  US  GEORGIA  IOWA  MONTREAL  TORONTO
0   apple     red       1   1        1     0         1        0
1  banana     red       1   1        0     1         0        1
2  banana  yellow       5   0        0     0         3        2
3    pear     red       1   0        0     0         1        0
```

Note that for each extra column you want to groupby (e.g. `fruit`, `color`, etc.), you'll need to add another item to the `level` parameter of the `groupby` call. So a more dynamic version would be:

```
cols = ['fruit', 'color']
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(cols), prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(level=list(range(len(cols)))).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: `get_dummies` is useful -- I'll definitely be trying to exploit that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use melt to combine region and subregion into a single column, then groupby and unstack:

```
(
    df.melt(["fruit", "color"])
    .groupby(["fruit", "color", "value"])
    .size()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    .reindex(
        pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["fruit"].unique(), df["color"].unique()], 
                                  names=['fruit', 'color']),
        fill_value=0,
    )
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
value   fruit   color  CANADA  GEORGIA  IOWA  MONTREAL  TORONTO  US
0      banana  yellow       5        0     0         3        2   0
1      banana     red       1        0     1         0        1   1
2        pear  yellow       0        0     0         0        0   0
3        pear     red       1        0     0         1        0   0
4       apple  yellow       0        0     0         0        0   0
5       apple     red       1        1     0         1        0   1
```